# How to get Wi-Fi or Mobile Network (4G or 5G) signal strength?

Tags: android, delphi

I have found several answers to this question, but not in Delphi.
Is there any way to do this in Delphi?

Comment: What have you found so far that you can't use? Android uses Java, and Delphi can use most Android Java-based APIs via its [Java2Op](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Java2OP.exe,_the_Native_Bridge_File_Generator_for_Android) tool.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be able to send AT commands to the Mobile device, i use the NrComm components for this, they work flawless.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).